# SQL error Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

```
function getjobid() {
global $geotag_table, $wpdb;
$qry = "SELECT * FROM mirdc_jo_form WHERE  jo_id = (SELECT MAX(jo_id)  FROM mirdc_jo_form)";
$desc = $wpdb->get_results($qry);

return $desc; }
```

can you help me guys.. i am trying to get the id from my table and try to show the data to my wordpress..

```
<?php  foreach (getjobid() as $generatedid) {
echo $generatedid;?>  #<------ this is the error
```

this is my wordpress code.. 
can you teach me how i convert the object to string.. to show the result to my wordpress.

Comment: the error is self explanatory that you are trying to echo an object. `<?php  $array_data = getjobid();  ?>` now print it first and then work accordingly. Show use what you got after printing this variable

Comment: Please Try 
$desc = $wpdb->get_results($qry,ARRAY_A);

Comment: uhmm sory sory i am just a begginer how i convert it to string ?

Comment: @manish jesani  the error was gone but it show "array" ..

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey print_r($generatedid);

Comment: @manish jesani  thank you sr .. it show the array.. iam not specific what i am trying to get to my table.. but thank you sr for helping me :D

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey what you want output ??

Comment: the output i want is to get my last jo_id from my table.. and print it to my wordpress..

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey Please see my answer for batter code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this is batter for your code**

```
function getjobid() {
global $geotag_table, $wpdb;
$qry = "SELECT jo_id FROM mirdc_jo_form WHERE  jo_id = (SELECT MAX(jo_id)  FROM mirdc_jo_form)";
$desc = $wpdb->get_col($qry);

return $desc[0]; }
$lastid = getjobid();
```

Comment: ohhhhh .. i see..sr can you explain to me why it is better to my codes.. sory i am a beginner and trying to study here :D

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey your query SELECT * FROM mirdc_jo_form........ you get all field from database table but as your requirement only one field 'jo_id'. so why are you get all field. 

so your information vary large database you get one field mysql query fast response from database otherwise your site SLOW....

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh isee thx for your informative information i will always take note it :D

Comment: sr i have a question.. what if  i dont have value on my table.. and if there is no data on my table. i want to have value of 1.. try an if statement and there is wrong to it

`if (!$lastid) {
    echo "Ther is no data";
    echo $val1;
} else {
    foreach ($lastid as $row) {
        $auto = $row->jo_id;
        if ($auto === ''){
            echo "There is no id!";   
        } else {
            echo $auto;
        }
    }
}`
the wrong part is when theres a value on my table it gives me a lot of `9999999` (my last id is 9) why it give me so many 9?

Comment: dumb of me xD why i put an foreach statement when i already get the `jo_id` 

`if (!$lastid) {
    echo "Ther is no data";
    echo $val1;
} else {
   echo $lastid->jo_id;
   

}`

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey Great.. last comment code is right. no requirement foreach loop.

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

`$generatedid` is an `Object` and containing entire row of data. You need to specify what column you want from that row.

You should try `var_dump($generatedid)` to view all the data.

```
foreach (getjobid() as $generatedid) {
    echo $generatedid->jo_id; // or whatever ID you want from DB 
}
```

Comment: OWWW i see that was it :( i am so noob THX SR T_T

Comment: i tried it  earlier  ----   echo $generatedid["jo_id"]; but it was wrong

Comment: It's an object, you should try `$generatedid->jo_id`

Comment: i am new here and it help me a lot when i don`t understand in programming :D  so many people want to help if i have a question..

Comment: It's a learning phase for all of us. Everyone was new at some point of time. Keep up the spirit and keep going. Wish you all the best. :)

Comment: please proceed.

Comment: what if there is no data on my table .. and if there is no value it give a value of "1" like string or integer. i try this code
 `  if ($id->jo_id==="") {
        echo "there is no value on talbe";
    }
but nothing happen :/